# Python - appending to same file from multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm writing an app that appends lines to the same file from multiple threads.

I have a problem in which some lines are appended without a new line.

Any solution for this?

```
class PathThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def printfiles(self, p):
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
            for f in files:
                print(f, file=output)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            path = self.queue.get()
            self.printfiles(path)
            self.queue.task_done()


pathqueue = Queue.Queue()
paths = getThisFromSomeWhere()

output = codecs.open('file', 'a')

# spawn threads
for i in range(0, 5):
    t = PathThread(pathqueue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

# add paths to queue
for path in paths:
    pathqueue.put(path)

# wait for queue to get empty
pathqueue.join()
```

Comment: Post some code, that would help.

Comment: When writing, check if the last character in the file is a newline. If it isn't, append one. Of course, that would require opening with r+ instead of a, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The solution is to write to the file in one thread only.

```
import Queue  # or queue in Python 3
import threading

class PrintThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def printfiles(self, p):
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
            for f in files:
                print(f, file=output)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            result = self.queue.get()
            self.printfiles(result)
            self.queue.task_done()

class ProcessThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, in_queue, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            path = self.in_queue.get()
            result = self.process(path)
            self.out_queue.put(result)
            self.in_queue.task_done()

    def process(self, path):
        # Do the processing job here

pathqueue = Queue.Queue()
resultqueue = Queue.Queue()
paths = getThisFromSomeWhere()

output = codecs.open('file', 'a')

# spawn threads to process
for i in range(0, 5):
    t = ProcessThread(pathqueue, resultqueue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

# spawn threads to print
t = PrintThread(resultqueue)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

# add paths to queue
for path in paths:
    pathqueue.put(path)

# wait for queue to get empty
pathqueue.join()
resultqueue.join()
```

Comment: in ProcessThread, the line -             result = self.process(path)
?
you dont hive process() method there..

Comment: You're suppose to define the process method to do what you want. I just modify to code to clarify this.

Comment: Is it necessary to keep spinning? Or is it recommended to use a blocking `get()`  on the queue instead?

Comment: Can we accomplish it also using `Lock` ?

Comment: @alper: yes, you can achieve it using Lock.

Answer (score 12):

the fact that you never see jumbled text on the same line or new lines in the middle of a line is a clue that you actually dont need to syncronize appending to the file. the problem is that you use print to write to a single file handle. i suspect `print` is actually doing 2 operations to the file handle in one call and those operations are racing between the threads. basically `print` is doing something like:

```
file_handle.write('whatever_text_you_pass_it')
file_handle.write(os.linesep)
```

and because different threads are doing this simultaneously on the same file handle sometimes one thread will get in the first write and the other thread will then get in its first write and then you'll get two carriage returns in a row. or really any permutation of these.

the simplest way to get around this is to stop using `print` and just use `write` directly. try something like this:

```
output.write(f + os.linesep)
```

this still seems dangerous to me. im not sure what gaurantees you can expect with all the threads using the same file handle object and contending for its internal buffer. personally id side step the whole issue and just have every thread get its own file handle. also note that this works because the default for write buffer flushes is line-buffered, so when it does a flush to the file it ends on an `os.linesep`. to force it to use line-buffered send a `1` as the third argument of `open`. you can test it out like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import threading

def hello(file_name, message, count):
  with open(file_name, 'a', 1) as f:
    for i in range(0, count):
      f.write(message + os.linesep)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  #start a file
  with open('some.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('this is the beginning' + os.linesep)
  #make 10 threads write a million lines to the same file at the same time
  threads = []
  for i in range(0, 10):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=hello, args=('some.txt', 'hey im thread %d' % i, 1000000)))
    threads[-1].start()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
  #check what the heck the file had
  uniq_lines = set()
  with open('some.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
      uniq_lines.add(l)
  for u in uniq_lines:
    sys.stdout.write(u)
```

The output looks like this:

```
hey im thread 6
hey im thread 7
hey im thread 9
hey im thread 8
hey im thread 3
this is the beginning
hey im thread 5
hey im thread 4
hey im thread 1
hey im thread 0
hey im thread 2
```

Comment: set() does not preserve order, so the "beginning" line may not actually be written after the first thread

Comment: @crypdick yep that was on purpose. the test above has each thread write a million of the same line to a file. the set then collects all the unique lines, we dont care about order of the output what we want to prove is that none of the lines are jumbled by multiple threads writing to the same file simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

And maybe some more newlines where they shouldn't be?

You should have in mind the fact that a shared resource should not be accessed by more than one thread at a time or otherwise unpredictable consequences might happen (it's called using 'atomic operations' while using threads).

Take a look at this page for a little intuition: [Thread Synchronization Mechanisms in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html)