# Need to write scraped data into csv file (threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, web-scraping

Here is my code:

```
from download1 import download
import threading,lxml.html
def getInfo(initial,ending):
    for Number in range(initial,ending):
        Fields = ['country', 'area', 'population', 'iso', 'capital', 'continent', 'tld', 'currency_code',
                  'currency_name', 'phone',
                  'postal_code_format', 'postal_code_regex', 'languages', 'neighbours']
        url = 'http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/view/%d'%Number
        html=download(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
        results=[]
        for field in Fields:
            x=tree.cssselect('table > tr#places_%s__row >td.w2p_fw' % field)[0].text_content()
            results.append(x)#should i start writing here?
downloadthreads=[]
for i in range(1,252,63): #create 4 threads
    downloadThread=threading.Thread(target=getInfo,args=(i,i+62))
    downloadthreads.append(downloadThread)
    downloadThread.start()

for threadobj in downloadthreads:
    threadobj.join() #end of each thread

print "Done"
```

So `results` will have the values of `Fields` ,I need to write the data with `Fields` as top row (only once) then the values in `results` into CSV file.
I am not sure i can open the file in the function because threads will open the file multiple times simultaneously.

Note: i know threading isn't desirable when crawling but i am just testing

Comment: have you tried keeping the file open and then just append on it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using some kind of [queuing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) or thread pools. [Thread pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) are really useful if you want create several threads (not 4, I think you would use more than 4 threads, but 4 threads at a time).

An example of Queue technique can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984760/5738367).

Of course, you can label the files with its threads id, for example: "results_1.txt",  "results_2.txt" and so on. Then, you can merge them after all threads finished.

You can use the basic concepts of Lock, Monitor, and so on, however I am not the biggest fan of them. An example of locking can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/rahulrajaram/5934d2b786ed2c29dc418fafaa2830ad)

Comment: Added some examples to my original answer.

Comment: if you can edit my code to do it that would be great,these examples seems pretty hard to understand then modify to my actual code