# How to specify the number of threads in python's "threading" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am new to python multi threading programming. But to run my function in a reasonable time, I have to use it. 
In an online tutorial, I found this basic code:

```
import threading

    def f(id):
        print ("thread function:",id)
        return

    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(i,))
        t.start()
```

The output I got is:

```
thread function: 0
thread function: 1
thread function: 2
```

In my actual program, I have parameters, which are a line to be read from a local file. I want to pass it to the target function. The target function performs some task, then writes results to a local file too.

My questions:
1) How can I specify the number of threads in the above code?

2) Is there any problem in making the target function writes results to a file? Can the multiple threads write at the same time? Are there any precautions to take to avoid mistakes?

Comment: You can pass the number of threads as your `range` i.e. `for i in range(your_var)`. For writing the file at the same time you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11983938/4636715) if you mean writing to the same file in parallel.

Comment: @vahdet Thanks. By writing to a file, I mean the target function performs operation in the input whi I sent in the args, then it writes the output to a file. Each input has its output written in a line in the same file. I am not sure how the multithreads will be writing the output to the same file? Is this will be managed by python? Or should I do any precautions. For example, multiple threads will write to the same line (each input should have its output in a single line). I want to be cautious not to cause data confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) How can I specify the number of threads in the above code?

The argument to `range` function are your number of threads.

> 2) Is there any problem in making the target function writes results
>   to a file? Can the multiple threads write at the same time? Are there
>   any precautions to take to avoid mistakes?

Yes multi-threading in python can be really weird if you are not careful on managing your data structures that your `threader` function is using. So in your case in a naive implementation you can have multiple threads writing same line to the file if the `write`operation is not controlled. That said what you can probably do in your case is to have the lines from input file put in to a `queue` and then `get` the line in the threader function and write it to the output file.